# Magento 2 : Add validation for tax/Vat number

Tags: magento2, tax, validation, vat

Can any one tell me how can i add validation for Tax/Vat number field. 
I want to make it numeric.
https://prnt.sc/ouycdv
What i have done till now in taxvat.phtml is

```
<input type="number" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('taxvat')) ?>" name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('taxvat')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getTaxvat()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Tax/VAT number')) ?>" class="input-number <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('taxvat')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?> data-validate="{validate-number : true}">
```

But only this is not working. what more i have to do? how can i show error message

Comment: Open table `eav_attribute` and find `attribute_code` taxvat and get `attribute_id` from it

Comment: Open table `customer_eav_attribute` and find that `attribute_id`. update in validate_rules column

Comment: @RkRathod Is there any way to do this from code?

Comment: yes using upgradeData you can update attribute

Comment: why not just impliment the tax validation settings in magento? https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html

Comment: @DavaGordon There is no option to make it numeric but

Comment: @RkRathod My query is giving error. update customer_eav_attribute set validate_rules = {"max_text_length":255,"validate-number":true} where attribute_id = '17';

Comment: @RkRathod Your soln did not work, it is still accepting alphabets

Comment: Have you tried adding the following data-validate="{'validate-number':true}" or data-validate="{'required-number':true}"

Comment: @DavaGordon Yes it is not accepting numbers, but it does not show any error message. how can i show error message like 'Enter only numbers'

Comment: id suggest trying the require number that should return a error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97616/discussion-between-dava-gordon-and-nafisa).

Answer (score 0):

use the oninput event,eg:

```
<input type="number" oninput = "value=value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('taxvat')) ?>" name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('taxvat')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getTaxvat()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Tax/VAT number')) ?>" class="input-number <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('taxvat')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?> data-validate="{validate-number : true}">
```

Comment: How to show error messager

Comment: what error message?

Comment: Message like 'Enter only numbers' .

Comment: use oninput event,just only input number.

Answer (score 0):

In phtml file add the below script

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Your form validation logic
        $('#your_form_id').submit(function() {
            var vatNumber = $('#your_vat_field_id').val();

            // Implement your VAT validation logic here
            var isValidVat = validateVatNumber(vatNumber);

            if (!isValidVat) {
                alert('Invalid VAT number');
                return false; // Prevent form submission
            }

            // Continue with form submission if VAT number is valid
            return true;
        });

        function validateVatNumber(vatNumber) {
            // Implement your VAT validation logic using regular expressions or any other method
            // For example, a simple regex validation:
            var regex = /^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9A-Za-z]+$/;
            return regex.test(vatNumber);
        }
    });
});
```

Replace "your_form_id" and "your_vat_field_id" with the actual IDs of your form and VAT input field.